# We can only change help text of event standard fields? Yes or No

Tags: helptext

We can only change help text of event standard fields? Yes or No

What could be the correct answer for this question?I had observed that even the task standard fields help text can be changed.

Please help me with the correct answer.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please elaborate more on the question! What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the **admin**, you can change help text on Event and Task fields both. *Screenshots attached below:*

**Task Screenshot**:

[image: **Task Screenshot**]

**Event Screenshot**:

[image: **Event Screenshot**]